# Timestamp in nginx logs changed after upgrading from 1.4.6 to 1.8.1

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-14.04

I have set the nginx timezone in /etc/init.d/nginx.
export TZ='Asia/Kolkata'

and the timestamp in the logs was working fine.

Later upgraded the nginx to 1.8.1 from 1.4.6 and see the log timestamp got restoed to the UTC timestamp. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe the config got replaced, what is the current TZ value?

Comment: /etc/init.d/nginx ->  TZ='Asia/Kolkata'. Its still the same

Comment: How did you upgrade nginx?

Comment: Probably newer version uses `upstart` job (`/etc/init/nginx.conf`)

Comment: Anyway, why don't you change system TZ?

Comment: how do we set the TZ in /etc/init/nginx.conf?